# Using triggers with auto increment field

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

So I am currently creating a database for a MMO (Massively mutliplayer online).
This database is going to list all of the items (armor, weapon, quests, npcs, e.t.c.) in the game.  I currently have it set to where each different category has it's own table within the database.  I.e a table for weapons, armor, e.t.c..  The data will be displayed in a table and the name of whatever it is will be a link that will take the person to a detailed page about whatever they clicked on.

For every table I have a ID field, that auto increments so each row has it's own ID.  But since I have multiple different tables the ids are going to overlap.  This isn't acceptable because of how the links work.  I created a 2nd field called "identifier" and the default value is based on each table.  So the default value for this column in the armor table is "armor".

I then created a third field called "combined", now here's the hard part! I created a trigger where before data is inserted into the table, the trigger combines the "id" field and the "identifier" field using CONCAT and puts it in the field combined.  Thus creating a unique id no matter how many tables I have.  But, since the ID field auto increments, the trigger is just putting a 0 where a different number should be.  Here is the trigger code:

```
set new.combined = concat(new.id, new.identifier)
```

This is before insert.

I tried doing a after insert but kept getting an error.  I've searched through questions here and can't find an answer for my problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this is to have a separate table for sequences.
Your schema then may look like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE weapon
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0, 
  name VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE armor
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0, 
  name VARCHAR(32)
);
```

A trigger for weapon table

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_weapon_beforeinsert 
BEFORE INSERT ON weapon
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO item_seq VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A trigger for armor table will be the same

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_armor_beforeinsert 
BEFORE INSERT ON armor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO item_seq VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now if you insert some data into both tables

```sql
INSERT INTO weapon(name) VALUES('weapon1');
INSERT INTO armor(name) VALUES('armor1');
INSERT INTO weapon(name) VALUES('weapon2');
INSERT INTO armor(name) VALUES('armor2');
```

Content of weapon table

```
| ID |    NAME |
----------------
|  1 | weapon1 |
|  3 | weapon2 |
```

Content of armor table

```
| ID |   NAME |
---------------
|  2 | armor1 |
|  4 | armor2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f67/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

If all of the "items" have the same number of characteristics why don't you just create an **item** table and have an enumerated type field to differentiate the type of item, e.g. armor, weapon, quests, npcs?